# Plugin form post cancelled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed an internal Google Chrome plugin that will extract the HTML of a page and submit it to a server side page through a form post.

Starting with the latest Chrome Version (56.0.2924.87) the plugin stopped functioning. When viewing the network information through the Google developer tools (right click -> inspect popup). I see that the event was canceled.

[image: Network Data]

Through searching Google  I was able to find the Google Event Log. Although I am unable to fully understand the information I see the below data 
[image: Event Log Data]

One thing I noticed was that it said "MAIN_FRAME_DEPRECATED" under the "load_flags" section. I am unable to find any information about this on Google.

This is the code from the plugin that is submitting the form.

```
  d = document;
  var f = d.createElement('form');
  f.action = 'https://***.com/index.cfm?***';
  f.method = 'post';
  var i = d.createElement('input');
  i.type = 'hidden';
  i.name = 'Filecontent';
  i.value = request.source;
  f.appendChild(i);
  d.body.appendChild(f);
  f.submit();
```

Is there any reason why Google is canceling the form post? I did some debugging initially through the server side page and I can confirm that the data is being submitted.

Comment: Extension process is isolated since Chrome 56. See if the problem is fixed in Chrome 59 canary. Or switch to XHR post method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to wOxxOm I was able to find the correct answer. I switched the form post above to an XMLhttprequest. The following does the same functionality but through synchronous HTTP requests.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url ="https://***/index.cfm?***";
var params='Filecontent='+encodeURIComponent(request.source);
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(params);
d = document;
d.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

The only caveat that I have found so far from switching to this code is that all of the URL's on the following page must be absolute. Any relative links will not function corect. That also goes for links that use `//` instead of `https://` or `http://`.

Comment: To make relative links work, manually add a BASE element in the new document with the actual URL of the remote page in href: `d.head.appendChild(d.createElement('base')).href = url;`